# Поиск аякс

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

Добрый день. Делаю поиск аякс.
Я хочу,что б я вводил в поле буквы и они отправлялись аякс запросом на сервер и я получал данные. Но если я ввожу одну букву, затем вторую...третью...то первые запросы уже не нужны, а они будут напрягать сервер. 
Как сделать так, что если более новый запрос по данной теме начался (в это время могут работать и другие аяксы, что б их не цеплять), то предыдущие запросы уничтожить.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Все уже придумано до нас.
В библиотеке [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/) имеется готовый модуль [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote) с достаточно большой функциональностью, в т.ч. с загрузкой данных с удаленных ресурсов, в т.ч. и с кэшированием этих данных, рекомендую ознакомиться, прозрачные примеры там есть.

Comment: а у него встроены "мозги", если я очень быстро набираю, что б он повторно не отсылал запрос? А то сейчас у меня получается: я ввожу символы, а у меня приходит одна таблица, затем вторая...третья, а я давно уже прекратил что-то набирать. Мне бы от этого избавится

Comment: странные вопросы, как для разработчика..

Answer (score 0):

Можете делать запрос аякс в случае, если в поле поиска введены слова, отделенные пробелом либо поставить ограничение на количество введенных букв, от 2-х, например.
Допустим, вы ввели начало слова Бан, тогда ваш запрос Like в базу вернет все совпадения, начинающиеся на Бан: Банан, Бан, Бангладеш. Тогда пользователю не придется продолжать вводить Банан, чтобы такое слово найти следующее после Бан. Так же можете использовать всякого рода ограничения на сервере и клиенте(по времени, числу запросов, числу результатов).
А вообще продумайте лучше логику поиска, слишком много свободы пользователю давать вредно.

Comment: А есть пример, как это сделать? У меня идёт один запрос, который обрабатывается,скажем 1 сек, а через пол секунды-другой запрос и т.д. Мне нужно отменить предидущие запросы